Is a partial effect plot for a GAM showing an average response when using the Gaussian family?
If an partial effect plot shows the individual effect of a smooth function on the link scale, where all other terms in the model are set to zero. And using a model with a Gaussian family, does the partial effect plot show the estimated mean response, so in the plot below at timepoint 4, the estimated mean response is 0.02? I think I'm getting a bit confused with my interpretation. Any clarification would be appreciated or direction to a resource that explains it in more detail.
e.g.


No; this is a partial plot so it is the effect holding other terms effects fixed to 0, including the model constant term (the intercept).
To get the estimates of the expected values of the response conditional on the data/model you need to add on the estimate for the model constant term.
You would get this using the predict() method for "gam" objects or my gratia::fitted_values() function.
For identifiability reasons, smooths are typically centred around 0 via application of a sum to zero constraint. This is why the partial plot of the smooth varies about 0.
